# Read/Write operations in MEAN.js

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, meanjs, yo

I have just started with `mean.js`  and am confused about its work flow. I created a new module using yo man generator. I need to be clarified about

- How a record is been added to the database ie where are the queries.
- How can a record be updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All CRUD functions are located inside `public/modules/yourModule/controllers` you can see `yourModule.client.controller.js`.

Inside you can see the functions `$scope.create`, `$scope.remove`, `$scope.update`, `$scope.find`, `$scope.findOne`.

These functions are called in your view `public/modules/yourModule/views`.

Inside you can see four files for your CRUD operations
`create-yourModule.client.view.html`, `edit-yourModule.client.view.html`, `list-yourModule.client.view.html`, `view-yourModule.client.view.html`.

For eg: in `create-yourModule.client.view.html` on `form` you can see `<form class="form-horizontal" data-ng-submit="create()">` the `create()` function is called.

If you want to see the mongoose model schema `app/models/yourModule.server.model.js`

For more details watch this good tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6rhBJX0L3TWYrwrQIi1_MzQDvVhkUVPI), (watch video 9 to 15)

Comment: Thank you.  My doubt is, when $scope.create is triggered in client side,  which function in the server controller is been invoked ? and  where are the mongo actions happening ?

Comment: check `app/controllers/yourModule.server.controller.js`.